# Somethin wrong with the code of UserStoredProcedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Need to create a procedure to add data rows into temp table for later optimizing the performance of the database. Sample code is used with northwind. Code should work, but i dont understand why it doesnt. EXEC command is used with parameter INT and can be anything. Any help with this? Procedure should add the data rows from [Orders] and [OrderDetails] to [Temp] but result is zero rows into table.

```
    /*
    EXEC dbo.uspAddRows 200 
    SELECT * FROM OrdersTemp1 WHERE OrderID = 40123
    SELECT * FROM [Order detailsTemp1] WHERE OrderID = 40123
    SELECT * FROM [Order details] WHERE OrderID = 11077
    DROP PROCEDURE dbo.uspAddRows

    SELECT COUNT (*) FROM [Order DetailsTemp1]
    SELECT COUNT (*) FROM OrdersTemp1
    */

    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspAddRows] @nmbr int
    AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON
        DECLARE 
        @NewOrderID int,
        @CustomerID nchar(5),
        @EmployeeID int,
        @OrderDate datetime,
        @RequiredDate datetime,
        @ShippedDate datetime,
        @ShipVia int,
        @Freight money,
        @ShipName nvarchar(40),
        @ShipAddress nvarchar(60),
        @ShipCity nvarchar(15),
        @ShipRegion nvarchar(15),
        @ShipPostalCode nvarchar(10),
        @ShipCountry nvarchar(15),
        @ProductID int,
        @UnitPrice money,
        @Quantity smallint,
        @Discount real,
        @OrderIdOrders int,
        @OrderIdOrderDetails int,
        @OrdersTempRowCount int,
        @OrderDetailsTempRowCount int

    IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.tables WHERE name = 'OrdersTemp1')
    BEGIN
    DROP TABLE OrdersTemp1
    END
    IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.tables WHERE name = 'Order detailsTemp1')
    BEGIN
    DROP TABLE [Order detailsTemp1]
    END

    CREATE TABLE OrdersTemp1 (OrderID int IDENTITY(1000,1), CustomerID nchar(5), EmployeeID int, OrderDate datetime, RequiredDate datetime, 
    ShippedDate datetime, ShipVia int, Freight money, ShipName nvarchar(40), ShipAddress nvarchar(60), ShipCity nvarchar(15), ShipRegion nvarchar(15), 
    ShipPostalCode nvarchar(10), ShipCountry nvarchar(15))

    CREATE TABLE [Order detailsTemp1] (OrderID int, ProductID int, UnitPrice money, Quantity smallint, Discount real)
        SET @OrdersTempRowCount = 0
        SET @OrderDetailsTempRowCount = 0

        WHILE @nmbr = 0
        BEGIN
            DECLARE ordersCursor CURSOR
            FOR SELECT OrderID, CustomerID, EmployeeID, OrderDate, RequiredDate, ShippedDate, ShipVia, Freight, ShipName, ShipAddress, ShipCity, ShipRegion, ShipPostalCode, ShipCountry
            FROM Orders
            OPEN ordersCursor
            FETCH NEXT FROM ordersCursor INTO @OrderIdOrders, @CustomerID, @EmployeeID, @OrderDate, @RequiredDate, @ShippedDate, @ShipVia, @Freight, @ShipName, @ShipAddress, @ShipCity, @ShipRegion, @ShipPostalCode, @ShipCountry

            WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
            BEGIN
            SET @OrdersTempRowCount = @OrdersTempRowCount+1
            IF @OrdersTempRowCount%100 = 1
            BEGIN
                PRINT 'Added ' + CONVERT(varchar,@OrdersTempRowCount) + ' row(s) into OrdersTemp1 table.'
                PRINT 'Added ' + CONVERT(varchar,@OrderDetailsTempRowCount) + ' row(s) into Order detailsTemp1 table.'
                PRINT ' '
            END

            INSERT OrdersTemp1 (CustomerID, EmployeeID, OrderDate, RequiredDate, ShippedDate, ShipVia, Freight, ShipName, ShipAddress, ShipCity, ShipRegion, ShipPostalCode, ShipCountry)
            VALUES (@CustomerID, @EmployeeID, @OrderDate, @RequiredDate, @ShippedDate, @ShipVia, @Freight, @ShipName, @ShipAddress, @ShipCity, @ShipRegion, @ShipPostalCode, @ShipCountry)

            SET @NewOrderID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

            DECLARE orderDetailsCursor CURSOR
            FOR SELECT OrderID, ProductID, UnitPrice, Quantity, Discount FROM [Order Details] WHERE OrderID = @OrderIdOrders
            OPEN orderDetailsCursor
            FETCH NEXT FROM orderDetailsCursor INTO @OrderIdOrderDetails, @ProductID, @UnitPrice, @Quantity, @Discount

            WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
            BEGIN
                SET @OrderDetailsTempRowCount = @OrderDetailsTempRowCount + 1
                INSERT [Order detailsTemp1] (OrderID, ProductID, UnitPrice, Quantity, Discount)
                VALUES (@NewOrderID, @ProductID, @UnitPrice, @Quantity, @Discount)
                FETCH NEXT FROM orderDetailsCursor INTO @OrderIdOrderDetails, @ProductID, @UnitPrice, @Quantity, @Discount
            END

            FETCH NEXT FROM ordersCursor INTO @OrderIdOrders, @CustomerID, @EmployeeID, @OrderDate, @RequiredDate, @ShippedDate, @ShipVia, @Freight, @ShipName, @ShipAddress, @ShipCity, @ShipRegion, @ShipPostalCode, @ShipCountry

            CLOSE orderDetailsCursor
            DEALLOCATE orderDetailsCursor
        END

        SET @nmbr = @nmbr-1

        CLOSE ordersCursor
        DEALLOCATE ordersCursor
    END

    SET @OrdersTempRowCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM OrdersTemp1)
    SET @OrderDetailsTempRowCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Order detailsTemp1])
    PRINT '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
    PRINT 'Added total ' + CONVERT(nvarchar,@OrdersTempRowCount) + ' row(s) into OrdersTemp1 table.'
    PRINT ''
    PRINT 'Added total ' + CONVERT(nvarchar,@OrderDetailsTempRowCount) + ' row(s) into Order detailsTemp1 table.'
    PRINT ''

    GO
```

Comment: "EXEC command is used with parameter INT and can be anything" - not really, since the first time you do anything with the parameter, it's to compare it with `0` and only run what's inside if that's true. This code can only run when `@nmbr` is `0`, which I suspect is not what you wanted. cursors and temp tables are usually a really bad choice too - they suggest you're approaching working with a database in a *procedural* fashion rather than looking for set-based approaches.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thank you so much! I spent a whole day tried to figure out whats wrong with it. My mind was playing tricks for me all along. Of course the loop should be ` WHILE @nmbr > 0 `  not  ` WHILE @nmbr = 0 ` My plan was to add as many rows as possible with TempTables so i can test how to create best INDEXES with INCLUDE to avoid TABLE SCANs. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first loop should be `WHILE @nmbr > 0` not `WHILE @nmbr = 0` or first loop cant set with the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspAddRows] @nmbr int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF ISNULL(@nmbr, 0) <= 0
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('@number must be positive', 16, 1);
        RETURN;
    END

    IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.tables WHERE name = 'OrdersTemp1')
    BEGIN
    DROP TABLE OrdersTemp1
    END
    IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.tables WHERE name = 'Order detailsTemp1')
    BEGIN
    DROP TABLE [Order detailsTemp1]
    END

    CREATE TABLE dbo.OrdersTemp1 (OrderID int IDENTITY(1000,1), CustomerID nchar(5), EmployeeID int, OrderDate datetime, RequiredDate datetime, 
    ShippedDate datetime, ShipVia int, Freight money, ShipName nvarchar(40), ShipAddress nvarchar(60), ShipCity nvarchar(15), ShipRegion nvarchar(15), 
    ShipPostalCode nvarchar(10), ShipCountry nvarchar(15));

    CREATE TABLE dbo.[Order detailsTemp1] (OrderID int, ProductID int, UnitPrice money, Quantity smallint, Discount real);


    DECLARE @MyOrders TABLE
    (
        SourceOrderId INT PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
        NewOrderId INT
    );

    --merge for capturing the source s.OrderId
    MERGE dbo.OrdersTemp1
    USING
    (
        SELECT TOP (@nmbr) *
        FROM Orders
        ORDER BY OrderID
    ) AS s ON 1=2
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN  
    INSERT (CustomerID, EmployeeID, OrderDate, RequiredDate, ShippedDate, ShipVia, Freight, ShipName, ShipAddress, ShipCity, ShipRegion, ShipPostalCode, ShipCountry) 
    VALUES (s.CustomerID, s.EmployeeID, s.OrderDate, s.RequiredDate, s.ShippedDate, s.ShipVia, s.Freight, s.ShipName, s.ShipAddress, s.ShipCity, s.ShipRegion, s.ShipPostalCode, s.ShipCountry)
    OUTPUT s.OrderId, inserted.OrderId INTO @MyOrders(SourceOrderId, NewOrderId);


    INSERT dbo.[Order detailsTemp1] (OrderID, ProductID, UnitPrice, Quantity, Discount)
    SELECT m.NewOrderId, od.ProductID, od.UnitPrice, od.Quantity, od.Discount
    FROM @MyOrders AS m
    JOIN [Order Details] AS od ON m.SourceOrderId = od.OrderId;

    --.... do stuff ...

END
GO
```